# Changing the look of a Firefox Addon SDK-based widget

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to style a widget created using the Addon SDK.

Most widgets get highlighted on *mouseover* by being enclosed in a sort of "box":

[image: highlighted widget]

How do I do this with the Addon SDK?

Answer (score 1):

This comes late, but here's a package that worked perfectly well for me:

https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib

It basically emulates Chrome's browser action and allows to open a popup easily. If the popup is not if interest, this also looks ok (but I haven't tried it) :

https://github.com/erikvold/moz-urlbarbutton